# Help getting all queues in a glassfish server

Tags: java, glassfish, openmq

I am developing a monitoring tool for a server runing glassfish, to do that, I have to get all the queues in this server.
I was able to do that connecting using tcp when it was running ActiveMQ, there was a DestinationSource.GetQueues() method.

I wanted to do that in OpenMQ, but after 4 days of research I couldn't find any sign that someone like that exists, so I gave up. My next try is doing that using JMX protocol. I could just connect, I am taking a look at all these MBeans, but I can't find any DestinationAttribute that may return the information I want.

I would like to know if anybody knows if it is possible to the all the queues.

Thanks in advance,
Oscar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that you have to use JMX and the MBeanServerConnection.invoke method